# Any trick to group by A and B or C

Tags: sql, group-by, clickhouse

I have a simple table:

```
┌─A─┬─B─┬─C─┐
│ 1 │ 1 │ 1 │
│ 1 │ 2 │ 1 │
│ 1 │ 3 │ 3 │
└───┴───┴───┘
```

Is there any trick to group by `A` and `B` or `C` (or `D` or `E` or ... arbitary cols count)?
Something like:

```
select A, groupArray(B) as B, groupArray(C) as C
from test
group by A and (B or C)
```

Expecting:

```
┌─A─┬─B----─┬─C─----┐
│ 1 │ [1,2] │ [1,1] │  // A and C matched for first two rows
│ 1 │ [3]   │ [3]   │  // A matched but not B neither C matched
└───┴──----─┴──----─┘
```

Script for clickhouse:

```
create table tests
(
    A UInt64,
    B UInt64,
    C UInt64
)
    engine = Memory;

insert into tests (A, B, C)
values (1, 1, 1),
       (1, 2, 1),
       (1, 3, 3);
```

Comment: What happens if you have an additional row in tests of (1, 2, 2)? It won't match to the first record, but will match to the second on A = 1 and B = 2. However, the 1st and 2nd records are already grouped by A and C. So is this new row grouped with the 1st group, is it a new group with 1,2,1 and 1,2,2 (meaning 1,2,1 is now in two groups) or is it in a group of its own (even though it matches the second row)?

Comment: @seanb Additional row (1,2,2) should be also matched with the second row as it has matched A = 1 and matched B = 2

Comment: Try this: 

SELECT 
    any(A) AS a, 
    groupArray(B) AS b, 
    groupArray(C) AS c
FROM 
    tests 
GROUP BY A, (A = B OR A = C)